# how create bootstrap nested with 3 row in mobile screen but in large screen one row with image on top left, two other in conner right bottom

Tags: bootstrap-4

thank for reading this..
I'm trying to convert my old website to responsive with bootstrap
some element need to take 100% with in mobile sm device but i get stuck.
I have create some codepen here could any one have look

```
https://codepen.io/binhaus/pen/GRpzKax?editors=1000
```

design look like this

```
https://imgur.com/3mbrYVn
```

thank for any tips

[Image of sample design layout in for bootstrap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/doQ1y.jpg)

Comment: im interested too